# O que fazer quando duas respostas me atendem?

Tags: debate

Recentemente fiz uma pergunta com dúvida em javascript. Logo, duas pessoas me responderam, e foram respostas perfeitas.

Porém uma com jQuery que deixou muito mais limpo o código e a outra com javascript puro. As duas me satisfizeram, e agora estou com receio de estar sendo injusto com alguém, como proceder nessa situação?

Pergunta: [Selecionar option de um select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183354/selecionar-option-de-um-select)

Comment: Aceite a que gostar mais, e dê um bônus de pontuação pra outra :)

Comment: Na tag da pergunta inclui JQuery, Acho que o óbvio é escolher a resposta com JQuery. Porém, contradiz com o corpo da pergunta onde não há JQuery.